# Please correct the error below i can not add the data in the model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? I always get the error:

[image]
[image]

model.py

```py
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime 
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
# Create your models here.

class Youtuber(models.Model):

    crew_choices = (
        ('solo','solo'),
        ('small','small'),
        ('large','large'),
    )

    camera_choices = (
        ('canon','canon'),
        ('nikon','nikon'),
        ('sony','sony'),
        ('red','red'),
        ('fuji','fuji'),
    )

    category_choices = (
        ('code','code'),
        ('mobile_review','mobile_review'),
        ('vlogs','vlogs'),
        ('comedy','comedy'),
        ('gaming','gaming'),
    )

    name=models.CharField(max_length=254)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/ytubers/%Y/%m')
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = RichTextField()
    city =models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age =models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    crew =models.CharField(choices=crew_choices, max_length=255)
    camera_type =models.CharField(choices=camera_choices, max_length=255)
    subs_count =models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category =models.BooleanField(choices=category_choices, default=False)
    is_featured =models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date =models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank=True )
```

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Youtuber
from django.utils.html import format_html
# Register your models here.

class YtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # def myphoto(self,object):
    #        return format_html('<img src="{}" width="40" />.format(object.photo.url)')



    list_display = ('id','name','subs_count','is_featured')
    search_fields = ('name','camera_type')
    list_filter = ('city','camera_type')
    list_dispaly_link = ('id','name')
    list_editable = ('is_featured',)


admin.site.register(Youtuber,YtAdmin)
```

Comment: can you show what the actual error says in the image as it shows there was an error but not what it was

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting.

Comment: I have uploaded the images  that error  i am getting I am not able to add the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using models.BooleanField as the category, so the only possible values are True and False. Change It to a models.Charfield and It should work.

This:

`category =models.BooleanField(choices=category_choices, default=False)`

Should be:

`category = models.CharField(choices=category_choices, max_length=255)`

Comment: Glad to help! If this was It please mark It as an answer so that other people find It easy :)